# What is the right way to initialize a constant in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, dependencies, warnings

I have a simple class that defines some constants, e.g.:

```
module Foo
  class Bar
    BAZ = "bof"
    ...
```

Everything is puppies and rainbows until I tell Rake to run all my `Test::Unit` tests. When it does, I get warnings:

```
bar.rb:3: warning: already initialized constant BAZ
```

My habit has been to avoid these warnings by making the constant initialization conditional, e.g.:

```
...
BAZ = "bof" unless const_defined? :BAZ
...
```

This seems to solve the problem, but it is a little tedious, and I don't ever see anyone else initializing constants this way. This makes me think I might be Doing It Wrong. Is there a better way to initialize constants that won't generate warnings?

**Update**: By way of a little more detail on how I'm using these constants, let's say I've defined a `Token` class that has constants for all the characters that are part of the syntax of some artificial language. I also have a `Scanner` class that reads a stream of characters, generating a `Token` instance for each one.

```
module Foo
  class Token
    LPAREN = "("
    RPAREN = ")"
    ...
  end

  class Scanner
    def next_token
      case read_char()
        when Token::LPAREN: # Generate a new LPAREN token
        ...
```

That is, when checking to see what kind of token should be generated for the given character, I want to use the constants defined in `Token`.

**Update 2**: [Jörg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532405/what-is-the-right-way-to-initialize-a-constant-in-ruby/4533168#4533168) revealed that the problem was probably in how I was constructing paths in my `require` statements, not in how I was initializing or using the constants. I rewrote my `require` statements to eliminate any manual path creation, e.g.:

```
# File: $PROJECT_ROOT/lib/foo.rb; trying to load $PROJECT_ROOT/lib/foo/bar.rb
require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__)) + "foo/bar"
```

is now written to rely on `$LOAD_PATH`:

```
# File: $PROJECT_ROOT/lib/foo.rb; trying to load $PROJECT_ROOT/lib/foo/bar.rb
require 'lib/foo/bar'
```

I removed the conditional checks from my constant initialization statements, and rake now runs unit tests without throwing any warnings.

Comment: Could you describe in more detail what this specific constant is used for?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The only way this can happen, is when `bar.rb` is `require`d multiple times. Which shouldn't happen, since `require` doesn't load files that have already been loaded once.

It does, however, only use the path you pass to it to determine whether a file has already been loaded, at least in Ruby 1.8:

```
require 'bar'   # => true, file was loaded

require 'bar'   # => false, file had already been loaded

require './bar' # => true, OOPS, I DID IT AGAIN
# bar.rb:3: warning: already initialized constant BAZ
```

So, you are right: this could very well be an indication that there is something wrong with your dependency management.

Typical warning signs are

- manually constructing file paths instead of just relying on `$LOAD_PATH`

  ```
  require "File.expand_path('../lib/bar', File.dirname(__FILE__))"
  ```
- manipulating `$LOAD_PATH` anywhere except maybe the main entry point to your library:

  ```
  path = File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__))
  $LOAD_PATH << path unless $LOAD_PATH.include?(path)
  ```

In general, my philosophy is that it's not my job as a library writer to figure out how to put my library on the `$LOAD_PATH`. It's the system administrator's job. If the sysadmin uses RubyGems to install my library, then RubyGems will take care of it, otherwise whatever other package management system he uses should take care of it, and if he uses `setup.rb`, then it will be installed in `site_ruby`, which is already on the `$LOAD_PATH` anyway.

Comment: Bingo. I manually construct file paths for require statements all over the place. Interesting, thanks!

Comment: +1 for answering the question and referencing Britney Spears!

Answer (score 6):

There's a good discussion on this in the comments on [this post](http://blog.jayfields.com/2006/12/ruby-constant-values.html). I think the following one puts it nicely:

> This irked me somewhat when I first
>   walked up to Ruby. It was a remnant of
>   my static type brainwashing. Three
>   things mitigate against this being a
>   real problem. 1. The warning. You
>   could argue it should be an exception,
>   but in reality, how would that be any
>   different in the case where some other
>   programmer silently caught the
>   exception? Which brings me to number
>   2) Don't work with morons. Only morons
>   silently catch exceptions and continue
>   and only morons change constant values
>   used in that way. Which brings me to
>   3) Neither of us is a moron, so you'll
>   be happy to know that anecdotally this
>   has never happened to me. It's really
>   because constants stand out in Ruby
>   anyway, what with their upcase, and
>   how often are you likely to have a
>   constant as an L-value in your code?

To directly answer your question, I wouldn't do anything to get rid of the warning. Just take the warning as just that, a warning, and move on.

Comment: That would be easier if I hadn't had it drilled into my head for years that warnings amount to bugs that haven't happened yet. Oh well...

Comment: "warnings amount to bugs that haven't happened yet" that is a good attitude to have, even in Ruby. I prefer my code to run correctly without any warnings, even test code.